Unable to run a query with dynamic datetime variable in ADF
I have created 2 variables  for the pipeline as below:


I am trying to run the following incremental query in the copy data activity
    @concat('
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
   [',variables('schema'),'].[',if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name),'] 
WHERE 
    UPDATE_DATE >  [', variables('startdate'), '] 
    AND UPDATE_DATE <= [', variables('currentdate'), ']')

However I'm getting the following error while running the pipeline :

Failure happened on 'Source' side.
ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax
near
')'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect
syntax near ')'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data
Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect
syntax near ')'.,},],'

The copy data activity screenshots:




"if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name)" it misses the expression check . if you looking to compare it with some values then add equals function. "if(equals(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),1),item(),item().name)"

This error is because the expression that you have given in the query is wrong. There are few changes you want to make in your pipeline to make it successful. Below are those changes.

You cannot assign an ADF expression as a default value to a variable currentDate. To assign an expression to that variable, add a set variable activity. Define the expression by clicking add dynamic content.

Expression: @formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')


The expression given for Startdate variable is also an invalid ADF expression. The correct expression should be given as @adddays(variables('currentDate'),-1) by clicking add dynamic content in Value text box.



Instead of using @concat() to form the SQL script, you can use string interpolation in ADF. Below is the correct expression.

SELECT * FROM 
['@{variables('schema')}'].['@{if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name)}'] 
WHERE  UPDATE_DATE >  '@{ variables('startdate')}'
    AND UPDATE_DATE <= '@{ variables('currentdate')}'


Hi , It's giving an error in the query
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near ']'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near ']'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near ']'.,},],'

Can you share the input of copy activity- Activity Runs. screenshot to get that

Have added the screenshots in the above qyestion itself

Can you check this screnshot? Here click on input of copy activity, and take the json and share here

Also , one more thing: Remove the brackets [ and ] around the  '@{ variables('startdate')} and '@{ variables('currentdate')}

I am unable to access the screenshot, it's showing 404 not found

Perhaps, you can check in mobile.

I have added the json code above

I have removed one bracket ] in the code. Check the edited answer. It will work without any error.

If this answers your question, you can click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows. Check this image

Hey it's still giving an error pointing to the actual values of ['@{variables('schema')}'].['@{if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name)}'], and says it's an invalid object name

I think you are not adding this query in add dynamic content. Can you do that and check
